# Send string to destinationViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have 2 screens in the so called app. First one(ViewController.m) gets the value and sends it to a method in ViewController2.m. Then, preloaded text of the label in the second view changes to the transferred string.

Cases are:

1) NSLog prints the correct output taken from the first page's textfield

2) However, setText method does not change the text of the label.

3) Strangely, same code works to change the text of the label in viewDidLoad.

```
- (void) setText:(NSString *)paramText {
    self.myLabel.text = paramText;
    NSLog(@"%@", paramText);
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.myLabel.text = @"try";

}
```

How I call the setText from ViewController.m:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ikinciEkran"]) {

        ViewController2 *nextController = segue.destinationViewController;

        [nextController setText:self.myText.text];

    }

}
```

Comment: are you calling setText method on main thread ?

Comment: It looks like you are doing everything right. Add some `NSLog`s to see that you reach `prepareForSegue:`, and that you enter the `if`.

Comment: I did and looks like it enters the if but I still get the same result for the label.

Comment: I cannot change the text of the label to static texts in setText: method.

Answer (score 0):

Your setter, you need to to :

```
_text = paramText;
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont know whether i understand correctly.But If you pass strings between viewControllers that works for you.For Example,Convert the VC1 textfield Value to String

```
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ikinciEkran"]) {
NSString *textLocalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",Viewcontroller1.text];
}
ViewController2 *nextController = segue.destinationViewController;
       nextController.introString = textLocalString;
```

then, Declare Introstring in Viewcontroller2

```
@property(weak,nonatomic) NSString *introString;
```

in ViewController2.m,put NSlog and Check

```
NSLOG(@"TransferString:%@",Introstring);
```

If you transfer nstring values between vewcontrller, this will works.

Comment: It passes the text fine but there is something wrong with the self.myLabel.text = paramText; in the setText method.